# sorting the value of multidimensional array by key

Tags: php

**table**

```
cat_id | cat_parent_id | cat_name   
---------------------------------
12     |      0        |  Car    
13     |      0        |  Manga      
14     |      12       |  Volvo      
15     |      12       |  Mercedes-Benz      
16     |      13       |  Naruto     
17     |      13       |  Hunter X Hunter
18     |      0        |  Animals
```

Im trying to get the categories in the db and put it in an array then after use that array to build the code for the drop down list. Here is the code BELOW.

```
while($row = dbFetchArray($result)) {
        list($id, $parentId, $name) = $row;

        if ($parentId == 0) {
            // we create a new array for each top level categories
            $categories[$id] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'children' => array());
        } else {
            // the child categories are put int the parent category's array
            $categories[$parentId]['children'][] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name); 
        }
}

$list = '';
    foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
        $name     =  "--" . strtoupper($value['name']) . "--";
        $children = $value['children'];

        $list .="<option value=\"{$value['id']}\"";
        if ($value['id'] == $catId) {
                $list.= " selected";
        }
        $list .= ">$name</option>\r\n";


        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $list .= "<option value=\"{$child['id']}\"";
            if ($child['id'] == $catId) {
                $list.= " selected";
            }

            $list .= ">{$child['name']}</option>\r\n";
        }


    }
```

final value of $categories array

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Car
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => Volvo
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [name] => Mercedez-Benz
                        )

                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Manga
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [name] => Naruto
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [name] => Hunter X Hunter
                        )

                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => Animals
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

But I want to sort the $categories by the value of the key 'name'.

I tried many times and so far this is my solution.

```
function sortByName($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}

usort($categories,"sortByName");

foreach($categories as $k => $v){
    foreach($v as $kk => $vv) {

        if ($kk == "children") {
            usort($vv,"sortByName");

            print_r($vv );

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is even that the first level key 'name' sorts fine, but my solution to sort the second level didnt work.

And also when the sorting happens the index of the array i sorted become 0 1 2 3.

like for example when i sort this by the value of the key 'name' 18 12 13 will become 0 1 2

```
Array(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => aa


        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Car


        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Manga


        )            
)
```

how can i sort but I also want 18 12 13 not change?

so I want my $categories array to be this

```
Array
(

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => Animals
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Car
            [children] => Array
                (
            [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [name] => Mercedes-Benz
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => Volvo
                        )

            )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Manga
            [children] => Array
                (
            [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [name] => Hunter X Hunter
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [name] => Naruto
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Comment: pretty certain I answered this very question from this very person this morning already.

Comment: read my question first, my first question to you is not same with this

Answer (score 2):

Too much effort. Use NAME as array KEY and then sort  by key wit [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: you could perhaps add more details. But you got my vote for the principle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that PHP doesn't interpret those numerical indexes as being keys, just indices, so that it doesn't retain them after the sort. If you convert them to strings and then do the sort, I suspect it will keep them. Alternatively, you could swap the numerical keys with your names (if names are unique, of course), do a simple ksort (as suggested in previous answers), and then swap them back afterwards.

Comment: it is just that the usort function (as sort) does not keep the keys. it is in the doc http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

you an use uksort to perform what you want. But there is something wrong in your design.

Like @Lukasz Kujawa said, php arrays are designed to be accessed in O(1). Your design, as C arrays, force everything to be O(n) and to add a step in the process.

I will give you the "solution" with uksort but to me it is not something good to do.

```
uksort($categories,function($a,$b)use($categories){
       return return strcmp($categories[$a]["name"], $categories[$b]["name"]);
}
```

Comment: what is O and C arrays sorry im a newbie

Comment: O(1) is a notation that means you can do some operations in a constant number of operation, whatever the values. O(n) says you do k*n+c instructions "n" is the parameter of your problem.
"C" is just a language. In this language, arrays are "true" arrays without the idea of "key value" association. So you're always using a search function to find the index and then access to the value to sort the array. In php, with this idea of key you can avoid the search.

Comment: but i will need that design to build my drop down list

Comment: not at all.
a drop down list can use key as name or value.
And if you want absolutely to use indexes, you can use a variable that count the number of objects. it is not forbidden.

Comment: like I said, it is a hack, something not clean but it works.
As a matter of fact, I use uksort and give a Closure (php 5.3 mandatory) as the comparison function. It is not overriding, it is just using the function. I declare a closure (an anonymous function that can use global variables) and give it to uksort